# Zurb Sass - Changes to "_settings.scss" not showing up - Windows

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I was using Zurb Foundation and have decided to start using it Sass and am stuck on the most basic of problems.

I've successfully followed this installation guide:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

I've successfully used Compass to create my project:
foundation new project_name --libsass

Here's the problem:
For a proof of concept, I'm just using the sample "Index.html" file and modifying settings in "_settings.scss", but I'm not seeing the change on the page.

(I've seen mention of needing to compile Sass, but I don't see it discussed in the doc.)

I've confirmed that my imports, etc. are all set up as per this doc:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/sass.php

Here is the effected code:
_setings.scss

```
    // Foundation by ZURB
// foundation.zurb.com
// Licensed under MIT Open Source

//
// FOUNDATION SETTINGS
//

// This is the default html and body font-size for the base rem value.
// $rem-base: 16px;

// Allows the use of rem-calc() or lower-bound() in your settings
@import "foundation/functions";


// Global

// We use these to control various global styles
$body-bg: #000;
$body-font-color: #c0c0c0;


// Panels

// $include-html-panel-classes: $include-html-classes;

// We use these to control the background and border styles
$panel-bg: scale-color(#000, $lightness: -5%);
// $panel-border-style: solid;
// $panel-border-size: 1px;
```

app.scss:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

I'm doing this on Windows (apologies if that makes you shudder). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In your app.css file can you see the changes you have made? Is it compiling the css file ok?

Comment: No, it isn't. Is it supposed to compile automatically or is there something that I need to do?

Comment: Are you using grunt to build the project?